# Sagemaker deployment with source_dir as S3 URI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment, amazon-sagemaker

I'm deploying Pytorch model saved as `.pth` to AWS Sagemaker. I specify custom `inference.py` file and my catalog looks like this:

```
|   my_model
|           |--model.pth
|
|           code
|               |--inference.py
|               |--requirements.txt
|
```

That's completely in line with [SDK doc](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/using_pytorch.html#bring-your-own-model). So I put the archive to S3 bucket, after that I define my model as following:

```
pytorch_model = PyTorchModel(model_data='s3://{bucket_name}/my_path/my-model.tar.gz',
                             framework_version="1.8.1", py_version="py3",
                             role=role, entry_point='inference.py')
```

Again, seems for me to be consistent with requirements. Still it returns error, claiming, that `inference.py` doesn't exist. I've tried to specify `source_dir` to be `code`. Still doesn't find. Then I tried to give it as path to my-model.tar.gz, as suggested in the `code`[here](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/model.py). Deployment succeeds, but then in logs I see it's asking me to define `model_fn` func, which is defined inside `inference.py` file and works perfectly if the code stored with the notebook, which deploys the model.

What am I doing wrong? How should I store model artifacts in S3 bucket and how should I define `entry_point` and `source_dir` to deploy it successfully?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't working in a git repository there can be issues with `source_dir` that is why I just define the `source_dir` as an absolute path instead
e.g for your example assuming your notebook is inside `code` directory

```
base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
source_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, '..', 'code')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify the `source_dir`.

Here is the sample notebook which shows "bring your own Pytorch model" deployment setup. Since the `sagemaker.pytorch.model.PyTorchModel` is based on `sagemaker.model.FrameworkModel`, you may use the `source_dir` when initializing the PyTorchModel.

Reference

- [Deploying pre-trained PyTorch vision models with Amazon SageMaker Neo](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker_neo_compilation_jobs/pytorch_torchvision/pytorch_torchvision_neo.ipynb)
- class [sagemaker.pytorch.model.PyTorchModel](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/sagemaker.pytorch.html#sagemaker.pytorch.model.PyTorchModel)
- class [sagemaker.model.FrameworkModel](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/inference/model.html#sagemaker.model.FrameworkModel)